converting query from DB2 SQL to oracle SQL
I'm new in Oracle so sorry for my question if you think it's basic..
we are migrating from a mainframe DB2 to Oracle in azure and we need to convert some DB2 sql queries to Oracle...
One of them is this one:
select fec_ult_conexion,cod_usuario,cod_substma, COD_APLICACION, des_servidor from DB2FO.FKTB001
where (fec_ult_conexion>(current timestamp - current timezone - 5 minutes) and
fec_ult_conexion<(current timestamp - current timezone) and cod_aplicacion in ('DLT', 'SIC'))
I have been looking for an equivalent 'current timezone' on oracle but I suppose it is not available and I don't know how the get the same query on oracle... I have gone through the TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ and the SYS_EXTRACT_UTC parameters but I don't know if I can get the query with these ones as they return this format 28-MAR-00 07.30.00 PM
Any help will be welcome...
regards
Borja
I have gone through the TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ and the SYS_EXTRACT_UTC parameters but I don't know if I can get the query with these ones as they return this format 28-MAR-00 07.30.00 PM
